# Tomcat 7 Virtual Host Added, Application Link Not Working

Tags: tomcat7, virtualhost

Using Apache Tomcat 7 as a windows service, with an AJP13 connector to connect Tomcat 7 to IIS.
I know how to update sites that are already hosted on this set up, but I've been trying to deploy a new application. Added the Host tag in server.xml

```html
<Host name="mySite.com"  appBase="mySite.com"

           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
```

Created a folder under Tomcat labeled mySite.com.
Dropped in the war file in the webapps Tomcat folder. It unpacked and deployed to the Tomcat manager site perfectly. When you visit Tomcat 7 manager app and click on the deployed link for the site, it loads the web application.

Then I copied the 3 folders from webapps\mySite.com to Tomcat\mySite.com\ROOT. Then went to the host manager and added the virtual host. The mySite.com link appears there in the list of virtual hosts, but when I click on it I get a 404 error- "The web page cannot be found" 
When you try to access the site from an outside connection, you get "The page cannot be found" and "No web page was found for the web address."

Did I miss a step setting up my virtual host? 
Did I add the virtual host App base incorrectly? currently it is set as C:\Tomcat\mySite.com.

Any ideas how to fix the error I am seeing? My log files don't say anything so I'm just not sure what is happening...

Also, all the tomcat docs say something about a Context file, but there is only one in Tomcat\conf folder that should be working for all sites hosted on this instance of Tomcat.

Also, all the other sites hosted on this Tomcat instance have one service and one connector port listed in the server.xml folder. So it's not a matter of adding another service. Adding another Host tag should have worked.

Any ideas on what I am missing or why this isnt working?
Would appreciate any help or ideas! Thank you!

Comment: "Then I copied the 3 folders from webapps\mySite.com to Tomcat\mySite.com\ROOT." What three folders? Could you provide a little more detail here please.

Comment: @MarkThomas the three folders are the  WEB-INF, org, and META-INF folders.